# gdb doesn't like fprintf(stdout, ...); and shows an error

Tags: c, windows, gdb

When I use gdb to debug some code, I'm presented with an error message about the stdout file not existing.

```
Breakpoint 2, logConsumer () at debuglog.c:210
210    fprintf(stdout, msg->pre);
(gdb) s
__acrt_iob_func (index=1) at E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/acrt_iob_func.c:11
11      E:/mingwbuild/mingw-w64-crt-git/src/mingw-w64/mingw-w64-crt/stdio/acrt_iob_func.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) s
[INFO ]
Breakpoint 3, logConsumer () at debuglog.c:211
211    fprintf(stdout, msg->msg);
(gdb) p stdout
No symbol "stdout" in current context.
(gdb) p stderr
No symbol "stderr" in current context.
```

As you can see on line 7, the output works fine(!), but `stdout` isn't a defined symbol.
Neither is `stderr`, but gdb doesn't complain when I use that.

**N.B.**: I know I should be using a format specifier to prevent any stack-smashing. The struct element isn't determined by user input and I was simplifying the following code to find the error:

```c
FILE *dest;
dest = stdout;
// dest = stderr; doesn't throw an error
vfprintf(dest, msg->msg, vargs);
```

Ultimately I would like to assign stdout or stderr to a FILE pointer, so I don't have to have an `if..else` block with `printf` and `fprintf` calls and repeated code.

Since the code functions OK both in production and debugging, I'm tempted to leave the `fprintf(stdout, ...)` alone, especially since the error only appears when stepping over the area in question -- if I delete all breakpoints and continue, no errors show and my output is as expected.
However, I'd really like to know why this happens!

---

I compile with

`gcc -std=gnu11 -g -Iinclude -c debuglog.c`

and link with

`gcc -o app minIni.o debuglog.o main.o -Llib -lkernel32 -lole32 -static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic -lmingw32 -lgcc -Wl,-Bdynamic -lglew32.dll -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lOpenGL32 -lfreetype -lavformat -lavdevice -lavcodec -lx264 -lavutil`

I use `gcc version 9.2.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)` and `GNU gdb (GDB) 7.8` on Windows 7.

Comment: In gdb, does `macro expand stdout` show anything?

Comment: `(gdb) macro expand stdout` 
`expands to: stdout` 
`(gdb) macro expand stderr`
`expands to: stderr`